# Python converting *args to list

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, args

This is what I'm looking for:

```
def __init__(self, *args):
  list_of_args = #magic
  Parent.__init__(self, list_of_args)
```

I need to pass *args to a single array, so that:

```
MyClass.__init__(a, b, c) == Parent.__init__([a, b, c])
```

Comment: You mean: `Parent.__init__(list(args))` ?

Comment: You probably don't need a *list*, but a sequence. `args` is already a tuple

Comment: You're not only limited to sequences, you can take iterables. I'm not sure since when exactly, at least since [PEP-448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Nothing too magic:

```
def __init__(self, *args):
  Parent.__init__(self, list(args))
```

Inside of `__init__`, the variable `args` is just a tuple with any arguments that were passed in.  In fact you can probably just use `Parent.__init__(self, args)` unless you really need it to be a list.

As a side note, using [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) is preferable to `Parent.__init__()`.

Answer (score 11):

There is this piece of code that I picked up in sentdex tutorials that deals with this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPp80YM2v7k&index=11&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcOdF96TBtRtuQksErCEBYZ

Try this:

```
def test_args(*args):
    lists = [item for item in args]
    print lists

test_args('Sun','Rain','Storm','Wind')
```

Result:

> ['Sun', 'Rain', 'Storm', 'Wind']

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something in the same direction as @simon 's solution, then:

`def test_args(*args):
    lists = [*args]
    print(lists)
test_args([7],'eight',[[9]])`

Result:

> [[7], 'eight', [[9]]]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

listname = list(args)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).